# Database not found, and IFEXISTS=true, so we cant auto-create it"

Tags: database, installation, h2

I install h2 database. when i try to verify  I typed, H2 Console → Click H2 console icon. Connect to the URL http://localhost:8082. the H2 database asked for database registration. It gave this error "Database  not found, and IFEXISTS=true, so we cant auto-create it"

I accidentally removed options generic h2 (Embedded). And I tried to uninstall and install again.  Now it doesn't show the option generic h2 (Embedded).

Please help me to solve this error

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're using an outdated version of H2 that throws an incorrect error message, the message was fixed in 1.4.200.

Due to applied security fixes, you can't create a database using the TCP, PG/ODBC, or web interface by default in recent versions of H2.

You need to find icon of H2 in the system tray and open the browser session from it by double-click or by selection of H2 Console item from its context menu. In this case the special random security key will be passed to the browser and it will be able to create the database with it and also access settings and tools without a password. It doesn't work when you open the URL without such key directly.

However, if remote access to the web interface of H2 was explicitly enabled, such transparent authentication is not activated by H2.

In that case you can use Create a new database item in the same context menu of the tray icon, or some other way described in the documentation, such as command-line Shell tool.
https://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#creating_new_databases

Comment: thanks for response. the problem I'm having is it doesn't show the options  "generic h2 (Embedded)" in the list

Comment: It's just a preset, you can fill the form by yourself. `org.h2.Driver`, some JDBC URL, `jdbc:h2:mem:1` for in-memory database, for example, and some username and password.